# Implementing an SHA256 algorithm in an FPGA - Error during timing analysis

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, hdl, vivado

I've been trying to implement a SHA256 design on my Arty a7-35t FPGA. When i try to implement the design, my timing fails wih the following values : WNS: -5.969, TNS : 428. It s my first time encountering this kind of problem and i am not sure how to tackle it. I will post some screenshots under with the error messages that i receive and my Verilog code + testbench .

I've tried adding some pipeline registers but they didnt help, maybe because i dont know where to put them. Thank you in advance.
My code contains the following modules:
1.Uart Receiver
2.SHA 256 parser : adds bits until reaches length of 512
3. SHA256_case: does the hashing
4. UART transmitter

```
module sendBytes (input clk,input rx, output tx);
parameter clk_per_bit = 868;
integer number_bytes = 32;
  wire done;
  wire [7:0]data;
  wire active;
  wire done_trans;
  parameter idle = 3'b000;
  parameter start1 = 3'b001;
  parameter update = 3'b010;
  reg [3:0] state;
  reg start;
  reg [255:0] store;
  wire done_hashing;
  wire [255:0] hashed;
  wire done_padding;
  wire [511:0] message_pad;
  reg [7:0] msg_trans;
  uart_rec #(.clk_per_bit(clk_per_bit)) receiver(
    .clk(clk),
    .rx(rx),
    .done(done),
    .data(data)        
    );
    SHA256_PARSER myParser(clk ,done,data,message_pad,done_padding);
    SHA256_CASE mySHA(clk,done_padding, message_pad,hashed,done_hashing);
  transmitterr #(.clk_per_bit(clk_per_bit)) mytrans(clk,start,tx,msg_trans,done_trans,active);
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    case(state)
      idle : begin
        if(done_hashing == 1'b1) begin
          state <= start1;
          store <= hashed;
        end
        else begin
          store <=256'b0;
          state <= idle;
        end
      end
      start1: begin
      if(active == 1'b0) begin
        start <= 1'b1;
        msg_trans <= store [255:248];
        number_bytes <= number_bytes -1;
        state <=update;
        end
     end
       update: begin
       if(active == 1'b0) begin
        if(number_bytes == 0) begin
            number_bytes <= 32;
            state <= idle;
            start <= 1'b0;
        end 
        else begin
            start <= 1'b0;
            store <= store <<8;
            state <= start1;
            end
        end
     end
   endcase
  end
endmodule

module transmitterr //100MHz clk
#(parameter clk_per_bit = 868)(
    input clk,
    input DV, //data_valid
    output reg tx,
    input [7:0] data,
    output done,
    output active
    );
    parameter  idle = 3'b000;
    parameter  startbit = 3'b001;
    parameter  readbits = 3'b010;
    parameter  stop     = 3'b011;
    parameter clean     = 3'b100;
    reg [9:0] count_clk = 0;
    reg [2:0] index       = 0;
    reg [2:0] state       = 0;
    reg active_internal   = 0;
    reg done_internal     = 0;
    reg [5:0] counter = 0;
    reg [7:0] data_internal = 0;
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        case(state)
        idle : begin
            count_clk <=0;
            tx          <= 1'b1;
            index       <= 0;
            done_internal   <=  1'b0;
            if(DV == 1'b1) begin
                active_internal <= 1'b1;
                data_internal <= data;
                state <= startbit;
            end
         end
         startbit : begin
            tx      <= 1'b0;
            if(count_clk < clk_per_bit - 1 ) begin
                count_clk   <= count_clk + 1;
                state       <=  startbit;
            end 
            else begin
                count_clk   <= 0;
                state       <= readbits;
            end      
         end
         readbits : begin
            tx      <= data_internal[index];
            if(count_clk < clk_per_bit - 1) begin
                count_clk   <= count_clk + 1;
            end
            else begin
                count_clk   <= 0;
                if(index < 7) begin
                    index   <= index + 1;
                    state   <= readbits;    
                end
                else begin
                    index <= 0;
                    state <= stop;
                end
            end
         end
         stop : begin
            tx <= 1'b1;
            if(count_clk < clk_per_bit - 1) begin
                count_clk   <= count_clk + 1;
                state       <= stop;
            end
            else begin
                count_clk   <= 0;
                done_internal <=1'b0;
                active_internal <= 1'b0;
                state       <= clean;
            end
         end
         clean : begin //dont quite understand why i need it? wait 1 clk cycle?
            state <= idle;
            done_internal <= 1'b0;
         end
         default : 
            state <= idle;
         endcase
    end
    assign active = active_internal; //good ideea to use register for the output?
    assign done   = done_internal;
endmodule

module uart_rec 
  #(parameter clk_per_bit = 868)
  (input clk,input rx, output [7:0]data ,output done);
  parameter idle = 3'b000;
  parameter start_bit = 3'b001;
  parameter readbit = 3'b010;
  parameter stop = 3'b011;
  parameter clean = 3'b100;
  reg data_valid = 0;
  reg [9:0] count_clk = 0;
  reg [7:0] mesaj;
  reg [2:0] state = 0;
  reg [2:0] index = 0;
  reg [3:0] counter = 0;
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    case (state)
      idle : begin
        count_clk <= 0;
        index <=0;
        data_valid <=0;
        if (rx == 1'b0)
          state <= start_bit;
        else
          state <= idle;
      end      
      start_bit : begin
        if(count_clk == clk_per_bit/2) begin
          if(rx == 1'b0) begin
          count_clk <=0;
          state <= readbit;
          end
          else begin
            state <= idle;
          end
        end
        else begin 
          count_clk <= count_clk + 1;
          state <= start_bit;
          end
        end
      
      readbit : begin
        if(count_clk < clk_per_bit - 1) begin
          count_clk <= count_clk + 1;
          state <= readbit;
        end
        else begin
          count_clk <= 0;
          mesaj[index] <=rx;
          if(index < 7) begin
            index <=index +1;
            state <=readbit;
          end
          else begin
            index <=0;
            state <=stop;
          end
        end
      end
      
      stop : begin
        if(count_clk < clk_per_bit -1) begin
          count_clk <= count_clk + 1;
          state <= stop;
        end
        else begin
          data_valid <= 1'b1;
          count_clk <=0;
          state <= clean;
        end
      end
      
      clean : begin
        if (counter < 5) begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
        state <= clean;
      end
      else begin
        state <=idle;
        data_valid <= 1'b0;
        end
      end
      default : 
        state <= idle;
    endcase
  end
  assign done = data_valid;
  assign data = mesaj;
  endmodule

module SHA256_PARSER(input clk ,input done_receiving,input [7:0] message, output reg [511:0]message_pad,output reg done);
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(done_receiving) begin
        message_pad = {message , 1'b1,{447{1'b0}},{48{1'b0}},{4{1'b0}},4'b1000};
         done = 1'b1;
    end
    else begin
        done = 1'b0;
    end
  end
 endmodule
module SHA256_CASE(input clk,input done_parsing,input [511:0] msg,output reg [255:0] hashed,output reg done_hashing);
  reg [31:0] sched [0:63];
  integer counter = 0;
  integer counter2 = 63;
  reg [5:0]counter3;
  reg [31:0] a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
  reg [3:0] state = 4'b0;
  parameter idle = 4'b0000;
  parameter sched1 = 4'b0001;
  parameter sched2 = 4'b0010;
  parameter sched3 = 4'b0011;
  parameter sched4 = 4'b0100;
  parameter hashing = 4'b0100;
  parameter clean = 4'b0101;
  //registre pt message scheduler
  reg [31:0] wire1,wire2;
  reg [31:0] rezultat2,rezultat;
  reg [8:0] index = 511;
  //registre pt calculul de dupa message scheduler 
  reg [31:0] sem1,sem2,ch,temp1,maj,temp2;
  localparam [31:0] a_temp1 = 32'h6a09e667;
  localparam [31:0] b_temp1 = 32'hbb67ae85;
  localparam [31:0] c_temp1 = 32'h3c6ef372;
  localparam [31:0] d_temp1 = 32'ha54ff53a;
  localparam [31:0] e_temp1 = 32'h510e527f;
  localparam [31:0] f_temp1 = 32'h9b05688c;
  localparam [31:0] g_temp1 = 32'h1f83d9ab;
  localparam [31:0] h_temp1 = 32'h5be0cd19;
  //2047
  localparam Ks = {
        32'h428a2f98, 32'h71374491, 32'hb5c0fbcf, 32'he9b5dba5,
        32'h3956c25b, 32'h59f111f1, 32'h923f82a4, 32'hab1c5ed5,
        32'hd807aa98, 32'h12835b01, 32'h243185be, 32'h550c7dc3,
        32'h72be5d74, 32'h80deb1fe, 32'h9bdc06a7, 32'hc19bf174,
        32'he49b69c1, 32'hefbe4786, 32'h0fc19dc6, 32'h240ca1cc,
        32'h2de92c6f, 32'h4a7484aa, 32'h5cb0a9dc, 32'h76f988da,
        32'h983e5152, 32'ha831c66d, 32'hb00327c8, 32'hbf597fc7,
        32'hc6e00bf3, 32'hd5a79147, 32'h06ca6351, 32'h14292967,
        32'h27b70a85, 32'h2e1b2138, 32'h4d2c6dfc, 32'h53380d13,
        32'h650a7354, 32'h766a0abb, 32'h81c2c92e, 32'h92722c85,
        32'ha2bfe8a1, 32'ha81a664b, 32'hc24b8b70, 32'hc76c51a3,
        32'hd192e819, 32'hd6990624, 32'hf40e3585, 32'h106aa070,
        32'h19a4c116, 32'h1e376c08, 32'h2748774c, 32'h34b0bcb5,
        32'h391c0cb3, 32'h4ed8aa4a, 32'h5b9cca4f, 32'h682e6ff3,
        32'h748f82ee, 32'h78a5636f, 32'h84c87814, 32'h8cc70208,
        32'h90befffa, 32'ha4506ceb, 32'hbef9a3f7, 32'hc67178f2};

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    case(state)
      idle : begin
        if(done_parsing== 1'b0) begin
            done_hashing = 1'b0;
            counter = 0;
            counter2= 63;
            state= idle;
        end
        else begin
          state = sched1;
        end
      end
      sched1 : begin
        sched[counter] = msg[index -:32];
        index = index - 32;
            counter = counter +1;
            if(counter < 16) begin
              state =sched1;
            end
            else begin
                state = sched2;
                index = 511;
            end
      end
      sched2 : begin
                wire1 = sched[counter -15];
                wire2 = sched[counter- 2];
                rezultat = {wire1[6:0],wire1[31:7]} ^{wire1[17:0],wire1[31:18]} ^ wire1 >>3 ;
                rezultat2 = {wire2[16:0],wire2[31:17]} ^ {wire2[18:0],wire2[31:19]} ^ wire2>>10;
                sched[counter] =(sched[counter-16]+ rezultat +sched[counter-7]+ rezultat2);
            if(counter == 63) begin
                    state = sched3;
                end
                else begin
                  counter = counter + 1;
                    state = sched2;
              end
      end
      sched3 : begin
        if(counter2==63) begin
            sem1 = {e_temp1[5:0],e_temp1[31:6]} ^ {e_temp1[10:0],e_temp1[31:11]} ^ {e_temp1[24:0],e_temp1[31:25]};
            sem2 = {a_temp1[1:0],a_temp1[31:2]} ^ {a_temp1[12:0],a_temp1[31:13]} ^ {a_temp1[21:0],a_temp1[31:22]};
            ch = (e_temp1 & f_temp1) ^ (~e_temp1 & g_temp1);
            maj = (a_temp1 & b_temp1) ^ (a_temp1 & c_temp1) ^ (b_temp1 & c_temp1);
            temp1 = (h_temp1 + sem1 + ch + Ks[32*(counter2+1) - 1 -: 32] + sched[63-counter2]);
            temp2 = (sem2 + maj);
            h = g_temp1;
            g = f_temp1;
            f = e_temp1;
            e = (d_temp1+temp1);
            d = c_temp1;
            c = b_temp1;
            b = a_temp1;
            a = (temp1 + temp2) ;
            counter2 = counter2 - 1;
            state = sched3;
        end
        else begin
          sem1 = {e[5:0],e[31:6]} ^ {e[10:0],e[31:11]} ^ {e[24:0],e[31:25]};
          sem2 = {a[1:0],a[31:2]} ^ {a[12:0],a[31:13]} ^ {a[21:0],a[31:22]};
          ch = (e & f) ^ (~e & g);
          maj = (a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c);
          temp1 = (h + sem1 + ch + Ks[32*(counter2 + 1) - 1 -: 32] + sched[63-counter2]);
            temp2  = (sem2 + maj);
            h  = g;
            g  = f;
            f  = e;
            e  = (d + temp1) ;
            d  = c;
            c  = b;
            b  = a;
             a  = (temp1 + temp2);
            counter2 = counter2 -1 ;
          if(counter2==0) begin
                sem1 = {e[5:0],e[31:6]} ^ {e[10:0],e[31:11]} ^ {e[24:0],e[31:25]};
                sem2 = {a[1:0],a[31:2]} ^ {a[12:0],a[31:13]} ^ {a[21:0],a[31:22]};
                ch = (e & f) ^ (~e & g);
                maj = (a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c);
                temp1 = (h + sem1 + ch + Ks[32*(counter2 + 1) - 1 -: 32] + sched[63-counter2]);
                temp2  = (sem2 + maj);
                h  = g + h_temp1;
                g  = f + g_temp1;
                f  = e + f_temp1;
            e  = (d + temp1 + e_temp1) ;
                d  = c+d_temp1;
                c  = b + c_temp1;
                b  = a + b_temp1;
            a  = (temp1 + temp2 + a_temp1);
            state = hashing;
          end
          else begin
            state = sched3;
          end
        end
      end
      hashing : begin
        hashed = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h};
        done_hashing = 1'b1;
        $display("h = %32b",h);
        $display("hashed = %h",hashed);
        state = clean;
        end
       clean : begin
        done_hashing = 1'b0;
        state = idle;
       end
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: This is a broad question to ask. The process involves finding the path from timing report and optimize that path using pipelining. Since the slack looks quite high, tool level optimizations may not be enough. But yet you can try them as well. Xilinx has couple of user guides on timing meeting. Find them

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the critical path is an internal path that does not meet the setup time for its destination flip-flop.

You must look at the timing report from Vivado and see which timing path is the critical path. The report should tell you which flip-flops are the beginning and ending points of this path. If you add a pipeline stage it should be placed between the beginning and end points of the critical path.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few dubious lines in your code.

For example

```
temp1 = (h + sem1 + ch + Ks[32*(counter2 + 1) - 1 -: 32] + sched[63-counter2]);
```

There are 4 additions, then you extract the content of a constant array at index32*(counter2 + 1) -1. Finally, you select a index that can range from 0 to 63 of the signal sched. You perform a lot of hidden operations is this line. It seems to be a C++ line simply ported in Verilog without any kind of consideration of how things work in an FPGA.

The sched[63-counter2] will implement a 32-bit 64 to 1 multiplexer. The combitional delay of such a multiplexer is likely to be high. However, counter2 seems to simply decrement, so I don't think you need a multiplexer, you might be better off with a 32-bit wide shift register with 64 levels.

You could check if Ks is actually implemented in a ROM. And perhaps you could pipeline the address.